# Notepad++: Reformat paragraph to fit into 84 character width in

Tags: notepad++

I have to write description section in my source code files. I try to fit this into 84 character width. Right now I try to do this manually. This means that when I enter a word into say line 3/15, I then have to fix the text in all subsequent lines so they remain within 84 character width.

Is there a way in Notepad++ that I select a paragraph and then execute an operation that shall format the paragraph such that it will limit the text width to 84 characters in all lines?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: So Notepad++ still does not have any such scripting capability?

Comment: Anything you can do would be something executed manually to split lines, not limit the feature test from becoming longer than 84 characters.

Comment: You can write a python script that will run via PythonScript plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  To illustrate how to split lines in Notepad++:

1. First, ensure Notepad++ has word-wrap enabled (**View** menu > **Word wrap**)
2. Then, place your text caret on column 84, then reduce the width of the Notepad++ window to only show 84 chars on-screen before word-wrap kicks-in.
3. Finally, select the text (eg, comments section) you'd like to fix, then either press `[Ctrl]+I`, or select **Edit** menu > **Line Operations** > **Split Lines**

The result is that only the selected text lines will be wrapped at 84 characters.

Hope this is helpful.